# Detect when Removable USB Volume Drive Devices are Attached or Removed – VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Below is some code I saw on a vb message board along time ago but I can’t remember where. It may have been vbforums.com. I made some code changes and then tested the code to have it throw a messagebox with the drive letter of the new usb device being attached or removed. It uses application subclassing to intercept the messages and checks if any are activated by a removable volume being Removed, Inserted, Attached, etc.. If it is then it will parse the volume drive letter of the device and throw a messagebox letting you know. USB devices like flash drives (Thumb Drives or Pen Drive’s as they are also called), external hard drives, etc. with a removable disk volume should be detected just fine. My testing recognized different usb volumes with no problems. You can use this code with VB.NET, Visual Basic 2008, VB 2010, 2013, etc. to check for both the arrival of usb volume devices and the removal. You can also make some changes to make it work for VB 6.0 as well. Visual Basic 6.0 will need an addiional API call or two for the subclassing portion.

Answer (score -1):

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef M As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    '
    'These are the required subclassing codes for detecting device based removal and arrival.
    '
    If M.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE Then

        Select Case M.WParam
            '
            'Check if a device was added.
            Case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL

                Dim DevType As Integer = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(M.LParam, 4)

                If DevType = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME Then

                    Dim Vol As New DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME

                    Vol = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(M.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME))

                    If Vol.Dbcv_Flags = 0 Then

                        For i As Integer = 0 To 20

                            If Math.Pow(2, i) = Vol.Dbcv_Unitmask Then

                                Dim Usb As String = Chr(65 + i) + ":\"

                                MsgBox("Looks like a USB device was plugged in!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The drive letter is: " & Usb.ToString)

                                Exit For

                            End If

                        Next

                    End If

                End If
                '
                'Check if the message was for the removal of a device.
            Case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE

                Dim DevType As Integer = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadInt32(M.LParam, 4)

                If DevType = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME Then

                    Dim Vol As New DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME

                    Vol = Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(M.LParam, GetType(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME))

                    If Vol.Dbcv_Flags = 0 Then

                        For i As Integer = 0 To 20

                            If Math.Pow(2, i) = Vol.Dbcv_Unitmask Then

                                Dim Usb As String = Chr(65 + i) + ":\"

                                MsgBox("Looks like a volume device was removed!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The drive letter is: " & Usb.ToString)

                                Exit For

                            End If

                        Next

                    End If

                End If

        End Select

    End If

    MyBase.WndProc(M)

End Sub
```

Comment: When answering your own question (or any question for that matter) please include some explanation to how the code works, and possibly share any links that you used as reference. Also make sure you include _**ALL**_ necessary pieces of code.

Comment: Without an explanation nor complete code this is not useful to future readers. Nobody will be able to use the code in your answer because it doesn't compile; it is missing a lot of variable/structure declarations necessary for it to work. Also, without an explanation (or at least a link for reference) future readers will have a much harder time understanding _**how**_ it works, which is rather important that one does when getting code from the internet.